# Rename Project in iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios4, project, rename

I just recently upgraded XCode to version 4 (4.0.2 to be precise). I wish to change a project name (it was very intuitive in version 3), i.e. change all relevant files names and the icon text on the phone itself, and I can't seem to find where I do it.

Anyone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tap to select the project name in the Project navigator, change the name, hit return, it will prompt you if you want to rename or not.